# Can we Apply LSTM-RNN for binay classification on numeric values data

Tags: binary, classification, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I want to apply LSTM-RNN for given below data set. Is it possible for this data set? If yes then how we apply LSTM Layer on this type of data set. Total attribute 67 and total row 890. and it is label dataset in the form of 1 and 0. A sample of the dataset is given below. If anyone has relevant python code then mention. I shall be very thankful.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is the data sequential? Do values in a row depend on values in the previous row?

- If *yes*, LSTM can help,
- If *no*, classify every row independently, e.g., using a feedforward neural net or any other standard classifier.